# Error Message: "The data types of the following form fields do not match the SharePoint list"

Tags: infopath, error, forms-7

I have a list on my work SharePoint 2013 that records two rich text fields:

- Bulletin - hyperlink
- Newsletter - hyperlink

When I try to open up the form attached to one of the products in my list, I get the following error message:

[image]

I have set up these fields as follows:

[image]

---

[image]

Please note that when I make a new list item, the form will open. IF I try to open older items, I get the error message.

Any all help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I go into the form in InfoPath, and I removed the offending fields, re-inserted them and then re-published the form. All seemed to work fine.